# Internal Server Error in phpstorm when loading css

Tags: php, internal-server-error, phpstorm-2017.1

I have Xampp running, and when I review the website it appears without css
so I tried to debug and I got this:
[image]

does this make sense ? the css are in this specific folder ( it was generated by bootstrap )

---

Ok so here are all the details.

I made some html files using Bootstrap, then I exported them to a folder, then imported them to PhpStorm. After that, I refactored the html files into php files and did some edits and then checked if everything is working fine, and it was. I could see the pages correctly on my localhost (using Xampp). After that I pushed the changes to GitHub to make sure I can revert anytime. After that I made some edits and the css stopped loading, so I reverted to the working version from github, and surprisingly it didn't work either. I even googled the problem and found some similar issues with other people and they suggested to hard refersh the browser ( ctrl + f5) and I did that, but nothing changed. 
here is the code for one of these html files:

```
<?php


<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>savvy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Features-Blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Features-Boxed.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Clean.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Dark.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Projects-Horizontal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Registration-Form-with-Photo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-image:url(&quot;assets/img/background.jpg&quot;);">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="height:90px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#" style="font-size:48px;height:55px;margin:-10px;padding:5px;"><strong><em>Savvy</em> </strong></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#" style="height:55px;color:rgb(0,2,6);font-size:30px;"><strong>Register</strong> </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" style="height:55px;color:rgb(0,2,6);font-size:30px;"><strong>Login</strong> </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" style="height:55px;color:rgb(0,1,1);font-size:30px;"><strong>Contact us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin:30px;background-color:rgba(236,237,236,0.52);">
    <h1 class="text-center">Why Savvy</h1>
    <p class="text-center">@ Savvy you can easily choose your path till graduation and even get to talk about it! </p>
    <p class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Learn more</button>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and Phpstorm doesn't give an error, as sometimes, that it can't locate the files. But the browser still shows the page without css.

Comment: `500 server error` is just a generic message, the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your webserver (Apache, nginx) and/or PHP logs.  What is the real error?

Comment: BTW post the text of your errors, not screenshots, this is not imgur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason behind this problem. it is the .htaccess file, delete it and works